# Using valid argument forms to derive a conclusion from given premises?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I am given the following premises:

\begin{equation} \sim p \vee  q \rightarrow  r \\
s \vee \sim q \\
\sim t \\
p \rightarrow t \\
\sim p \wedge r \rightarrow \sim s \end{equation}

I am suppose to derive $$\sim q$$ from the above.

I am able to get $$\sim p$$ from the third and fourth premises, but I am not sure how to apply the argument forms to the other premises. I am unsure on how to proceed, should I break the premises with three terms into a two parts first?

How would I go about apply argument forms to get the conclusion?

Comment: As you say yourself, you do that by applying those argument forms.  So, did you try that? Where did you get stuck? At this site we really like to see some effort. And, if you show us what you did, we can pinpoint specific problems you might have with the material, and give you some specific pointers to get better at this.

Comment: @Bram28 Thanks for the reply. I've updated my question with what I tried, albeit it is only one premise. The examples I manage to get online usually only have two terms instead of three i.e. p, q, r.

Comment: Yes, I see that and appreciate that ... actually, look at the first premise now ... you have ~p, and the first premise says that if you have ~pvq, then you can get r ...OK, so ~pvq is not the same as ~p ... but can you get ~pvq from ~p?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align} \lnot p \vee  q \rightarrow  r \tag{1}\\
s \vee \lnot q \tag{2} \\
\lnot  t \tag{3}\\
p \rightarrow t \tag{4}\\
\lnot p \wedge r \rightarrow \lnot s \tag{5}\end{align}

As you note in your post, from the fourth premise we have $p\to t$, and we have, in the third premise, $\lnot t$.  By modus tollens, we derive $\lnot p$.

Now, since we've derived $\lnot p$ from premises (3), (4), we also have $\lnot p \lor q$, by "addition" to $\lnot p$, (also called  "or-introduction" which is shorthand for disjunction introduction).

And from $\lnot p \lor q$, together with the premise (1), we have $r$ by modus ponens.

Now, since we already deduced $\lnot p$, and we just deduced $r$, we can use "And-introduction (conjunction-introduction)" to get $\lnot p \land r$.

Given $\lnot p \land r$, and premise (5): $(\lnot p \land r) \to \lnot s$, we have, by modus ponens, $\lnot s$.

But given our premise (2), $s \lor \lnot q,$ together with $\lnot s$, we deduce $\lnot q$, as desired.

Comment: [This list/entry from Wikipedia on propositional logic and rules of inference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propositional_calculus#Example_2._Natural_deduction_system) may help you recoginize that given $a$, it is valid to deduce $a \lor x$ for any proposition $x$ (other than $\lnot a$)